# Stanley Cup Finals matchup where both finalists needed 7 games in conference finals

Tags: ice-hockey, nhl, stanley-cup

Riddle me this....

When was the last time (if ever) the Stanley Cup Finals featured two teams that had both won game 7 on the road in their respective conference finals?

Answer (score 6):

According to the [list of conference finals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NHL_Conference_Finals#Prince_of_Wales_Conference.2FEastern_Conference) on Wikipedia:

- Eastern conference final had 7 games in: 1988, 1994, 1996, 2000, 2003, 2004, 2006, 2011 and 2015.
- Western conference final had 7 games in: 1986, 1993, 1999, 2000, 2002, 2014 and 2015.

So we see that the both SC finalists needed 7 games in conference finals only in 2000 and 2015.<sup>1,2</sup>

In [2000](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Stanley_Cup_playoffs) Dallas Stars won their series as the home team. New Jersey Devils won their series as the away team and they also won the 2000 Stanley Cup. (They won the final series in 6 games.)

So in [2015](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015_Stanley_Cup_playoffs) we see for the first time situations that both conference finals took 7 games and in both of them the away team won. (Tampa Bay Lightning and Chicago Blackhawks, Blackhawks won the finals in 6 games.)

The fact that this was the first time since 2000 when both conference finals needed 7 games was mentioned, for example, here:

- [Ducks, Blackhawks vie for Cup Final in Game 7](http://www.nhl.com/ice/news.htm?id=769155) - nhl.com
- Reddit: [For the first time since 2000 both Conference Finals go 7 games](https://www.reddit.com/r/hockey/comments/37jn5v/for_the_first_time_since_2000_both_conference/)
- [#NHLPlayoffs: From east to west, Game 7 is the best](http://www.cbc.ca/sports/hockey/nhl/nhlplayoffs-from-east-to-west-game-7-is-the-best-1.3090506) - cbasports
- [Double sevens make for rare conclusion in NHL conference finals](http://www.sportingnews.com/list/4645567-stanley-cup-playoffs-conference-finals-game-7-rangers-blackhawks-ducks-lightning) - Sporting New
- [NHL's wildly entertaining conference finals set for endings they deserve](http://www.cbssports.com/nhl/eye-on-hockey/25199284/nhls-wildly-entertaining-conference-finals-set-for-endings-they-deserve) - CBSSports

<sup>1</sup> The CBSSports article I linked claims that: *"For just the third time in NHL history, both conference finals will be decided by a Game 7."* But I was not able to find the third time when this happened.

<sup>2</sup> Both Stanley Cup semifinals (and also the Stanley Cup final) were decided in the 7th game in [1964](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1964_Stanley_Cup_playoffs#Playoff_bracket). But at the time the NHL was not divided into conferences. As far as I can tell from the information in the Wikipedia article I linked, the best-of-seven format used in this season was the same as the one used nowadays. So it seems that in that case the away teams won both semifinal series in seven games. (And the finals were decided in the 7th game, too.)

Comment: Thanks for the response Martin. Watching the Blackhawks/Ducks last night, I was wondering how rare this particular situation is. Considering how long the Stanley Cup has been around, I am blown away!